# Pass parameter to shel script in remote machine via jenkins

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, devops

I'm trying to pass the value of the parameter "USERNAME" to a shell script in my remote host. And after that i'm trying to access it from that script. Jenkins job's ssh section and in the script, it is as below.

JENKINS JOB'S SSH PART

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -tt shan@<ip-addr> '
ls -la /opt/scripts/
/opt/scripts/./name_script.sh ${USERNAME}
'
```

SCRIPT

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

script is perfectly working when i try the below within the server.

```
./name_script.sh Shan
```

But to the above posted scenario, its not working. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Could you try to print the USERNAME variable in your first script. Also try one more thing, Instead of single quotes try 3 single quotes. ''' your code '''

Comment: There's an option to inject environment variables or prepare environment for run. Do you have those set?

Comment: @pratikvasa When i try to print the username, its working fine.

Comment: @IanW Hi Ian, in this script what i'm trying to do is, i'm executing a shell script in my remote server. so that script will do the job in that particular host.

Comment: does it print anything at all?

Comment: Change your script to `echo :$1:` and you'll probably find you get "::". Add a line`set` to see the env vars. Is ${USERNAME} there? Not sure if it gets set. Interesting [discussion here](https://serverfault.com/q/593399/189417) or read man page. You so may need a ";" at the end of each line. You could try echo $q >somefile  and see if it's just putting output back to you via tty.

Comment: @IanW Hi Ian, Actually the issue was i needed to add "${USERNAME}" instead of ${USERNAME}. Thank you very much for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

The issue was i needed to add "${USERNAME}" instead of ${USERNAME}